# Error Spring integration xsd for aws sqs

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-integration, amazon-sqs

I'm getting an error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 44; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aws-messaging:sqs-async-client'.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:452)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3230)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1911)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:760)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Confin.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
```

I'm using the following xsd's:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aws-messaging="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd"
default-lazy-init="true">

<description>
Connects to SQS, fetches the compressed payload and sends to 
uncompress channel
Step 1 of the flow
</description>

<aws-messaging:sqs-async-client id="sqs"/>

<aws-context:context-credentials>
<aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="${aws.accesskey}"
secret-key="${aws.secretkey}"/>
</aws-context:context-credentials>
```

This used to work before. I used this as a template: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/aws/config/xml/SqsMessageHandlerParserTests-context.xml

Can you please help? Did something change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look , what you have for namespace prefixes:

```
xmlns:aws-messaging="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
```

And what has to be:

```
       xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws"
   xmlns:aws-messaging="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging"
      xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
```

Plus you have to add their `schemaLocation`s as well:

```
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging/spring-cloud-aws-messaging.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd
```

Comment: Well, you have to be sure that all those jars are in the classpath and your IDE is Spring aware, like IDEA or STS

Comment: But anyway your sample isn't going to work well there as well. Just because it isn't correct

Comment: Can you please point me to some documentation to make this work? I have been looking at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws

Comment: Not sure what docs you need. That's not that project responsibility and I've shown you the correct way to declare Spring namespaces. Everything rest is up to your IDE. Or just ignore it and build project with Maven or Gradle.

Comment: It will be useful to know the version of spring-aws to use. I now get: ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SqsMessageDeletionPolicy .I tried adding: compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-aws', version: '0.5.0.RELEASE' but that did not help

Comment: Not sure why don't use the latest version according Maven: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spring-integration-aws%22 and rely on its transitive dependencies

Comment: I tried that.my gradle dependancies are: compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-aws-messaging', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-aws', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-aws', version: '1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-dependencies', version: 'Brixton.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
Now I get a new error, like:AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration$AbstractRegistrar.class] cannot be opened

Comment: I think I'm not having the right combination of dependancies but I'm not sure how i can find them. I can open this as a new ticket if you would like since the original xsd issue is now solved.

Comment: Well, that's not readable from the comment. Why don't *edit* your question acuratelly with that additional info?

Comment: That's correct way to think here on SO: one problem per thread. If XSD problem has gone and my answer is helpful, then accept it to help other people to be sure that we have a solution here.

Comment: Accepted answer and created new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180925/unable-to-figure-out-exhaustive-list-of-spring-integration-gradle-dependancies-f .  Thanks Artem