# Unable to figure out exhaustive list of Spring integration gradle dependancies for aws

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-integration, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to use spring-integration for publishing, subscribing from sqs. I started with the following for my gradle dependancies:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-aws-messaging', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-aws', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE'
```

It was complaining about:

```
ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.cloud.
aws.messaging.listener.SqsMessageD‌​eletionPolicy
```

I then went ahead and added:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-
starter-aws', version: '1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-
dependencies', version: 'Brixton.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
```

and now I get:

```
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/jdbc/config/annotation/AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration$AbstractRegistrar.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I don't use jdbc in my project at all so I think I'm using the wrong set of dependancies. What am i doing wrong here? Can someone help with the complete list of transitive dependancies I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this combination:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-aws', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-aws-messaging', version: '1.1.0.RELEASE'
```

Nothing more as far as I know.

Right, the `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` dependency of the `spring-integration-aws` is optional, but the version used for `spring-integration-aws:1.0.0.RELEASE` is definitely `1.1.0.RELEASE`, not `1.0.0.RELEASE`.